Android room when put just % in search query it return all results
When i put just "%" in search query room returns all results
example of query SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%' || :search || '%'
When i put % in searh query i need just elements what contain this special symbol.

What exactly is the query you want to run and what do the results you are looking for look like? What is the schema of your table?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A %, as it is an operator for the LIKE clause, has to be ESCAPEd so that it is taken as a literal value rather than an embedded operator.

NOTE an _ is also an operator for the LIKE clause (single wild character). As such, you may wish to handle them in a similar manner (i.e. escape them).

you may wish to refer to The LIKE, GLOB, REGEXP, MATCH, and extract operators, especially the second paragraph of the linked section.

Here's the syntax for the LIKE clause including the ESCAPE clause  as found at https://www.sqlite.org/draft/syntax/expr.html



The result that you want can be achieved by using the ESCAPE keyword, followed by an expression that defines the single escape character.
If the stored value was, for example, abcdef% and the literal value to be searched were % then then instead of using LIKE '%'||:search||'%' (where search is %). You would need to change the value of search to include an escape character that prefixes the '%'.
If the chosen escape character were, for example, @ then you could replace the % with @% of the search value along with including the ESCAPE clause.
e.g. LIKE '%'||:search||'%' ESCAPE '@'
As the escape character, can itself be escaped, you may wish to consider first replacing the escape character with 2 escape characters (which equates to itself) and then replacing the % with the escaped % (@%).
So say that the search value were A@% then it would be changed first to A@@% (i.e. the escape character has been escaped) and then to A@@@% so that the % is also escaped.
Here's a demo using raw SQL (that can be used in an SQLite tool):-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (v TEXT);
/* insert some data for testing */
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('abcdef%'),('xyz'),('a@%');

SELECT * FROM t WHERE v LIKE '%'||'%'||'%';  /* AS per the question i.e. % is considered operator not literal value */
SELECT * FROM  t WHERE v LIKE '%'||'@%'||'%' ESCAPE '@'; /* now the % has been escaped */
SELECT * FROM  t WHERE v LIKE '%'||'@@@'||'%' ESCAPE '@'; /* now the escape character has also been escaped as well as the %*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t; /* cleanup testing environment */

Running the above in an SQLite tool (Navicat for SQLite used) results in:-



i.e. all rows as per the question




i.e. just the rows that have a % in the v column




i.e. ONLY the row that contains @%



